# Verbs coming before ～てからでないと

Tags: grammar, usage, jlpt

I encountered the following multiple-choice question on page 19 (question 1 in section 5) of my JLPT N2 grammar textbook 「新完全マスター文法　日本語能力試験Ｎ２」:

> （　　　）からでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。
>
> ａ 車の運転ができて　　ｂ いいアイディアがあって　　ｃ お金の準備ができて

The answer is 「ｃ お金の準備ができて」.  I chose the correct option and understand why it is correct, but I am not sure why the other options are wrong.  My textbook explains ～てからでないと as

> #### ～てからでないと・～てからでなければ
>
> ～した後でなければ、あることが実現しない。
>
> 後には、否定的な意味の文が来る。

The explanation can be translated as "not until".  Now, 新しい事業に取りかかれない is obviously of negative meaning (否定的な意味), so all three options seem to make sense to me:

> (a) （？）車の運転ができてからでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。
>
> I cannot set about a new undertaking until I am able to drive.

> (b) （？）いいアイディアがあってからでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。
>
> I cannot set about a new undertaking until a good idea comes up.

> (c) お金の準備ができてからでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。
>
> I cannot set about a new undertaking until monetary preparation is done.

Other than the fact that the logical connection in (a) is not obvious (perhaps the new undertaking requires driving skills), I cannot seem to find any errors in these sentences.  Why are options (a) and (b) wrong, and what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the sentence is expected to describe a **change** that makes it possible for what is described in the second part to happen. お金の準備ができる is such a change.

Though the same verb is used, 車の運転ができる doesn’t describe a change but a state, or a static property of someone. The sentence would sound more natural if you convert it into a change like this.

> 車の運転ができるようになってからでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。

いいアイデアがある is also a state. You would have to make it a change. Here is one way to do it.

> いいアイデアを思いついてからでないと、新しい事業に取りかかれない。